# System Verilog, how to sum array values?

Tags: for-loop, sum, verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I'm trying to sum array values using System Verilog.

My data are declared like this:

```
reg     signed  [23:0]    n2 [31:0];
reg     signed  [15:0]    w2 [195:0];
```

`w2` is a reg with values stock in it.

```
for(int i2=0; i2<32; i2++) begin
        for(int  j2=0; j2<196; j2++) begin
            n2[i2] <= n2[i2] + w2[j2];
        end
    end
end
```

I need to sum 196 * 16bit (*32), so it requires a 24 bit(*32)?

I tried to simulate my design, and I only have X in `n2` reg.

Also, I run the RTL Analysis and open the elaborated design, and I have a warning like this:

> [Synth 8-324] index 10 out of range

It's pointing to the line:

```
for(int  j2=0; j2<196; j2++) begin
```

but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

> I only have X in n2 reg.

Of course you have.
At the start n2 is not initialized so it contains all X-es. Now you add numbers to X-es which still give you X-es. It is the same as if you would add to an uninitialized variable in most languages.
Try this:

```
for(int i2=0; i2<32; i2++) begin
    n2[i2] <= w2[0];
    for(int  j2=1; j2<196; j2++) begin
        n2[i2] <= n2[i2] + w2[j2];
    end
end
```

(I have kept your `<=` as I don't know the context. But I have doubts this is correct)

> I have a warning ...

I can't help you with your synth warning. I don't see anything obvious wrong but then again you provided only a very small snippet of code.